# How to access all entities of a base class in Rooms?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have two sub classes and a base that look like this:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    public String name;
}

@Entity
public class Student extends User {
    public String studentNumber;
    public int grade;
}

@Entity
public class Teacher {
    public int employeeId;
    public string salutation;
}
```

How can I get a list of all Users which includes any Student users or Teacher users?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to use base classes in such a way (this schema doesn't follow [database normalisation principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and you should do additional boilerplate code during migration after you decide to change your base class in some way).

Common way in your case at relational databases - is to use relations between tables using foreign keys. In that way tables `Student` and `Teacher` wouldn't be affected (I mean on the database's structure level) after `User`'s table changes.

So consider next tables' schema (you could add @ForeignKey as well):

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;
}

@Entity
public class Student { // <- doesn't extend any class
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id; // <- primary key for student
    public int userId; // <- foreign key for user, you should fill it explicitly
    public String studentNumber;
    public int grade;
}

@Entity
public class Teacher { // <- doesn't extend any class
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id; // <- primary key for teacher, but maybe it could be employeeId ?
    public int userId; // <- foreign key for user, you should fill it explicitly 
    public int employeeId;
    public string salutation;
}
```

In that schema to get all users that are students or teachers you can with next query in DAO:

```
SELECT * FROM user JOIN student on user.id=student.userId UNION SELECT * FROM user JOIN teacher on user.id=teacher.userId
```